# Jquery update text on selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clone

I'm trying to update text inside clicked element, but both the div gets updated on the same time. trying to play around the same code without including Id or further class.

Trying to find the solution since morning.

Here is the the live fiddle to playground:  https://jsfiddle.net/vinayak5192/63ujzwwn/2/

```js
$(".edit_me").hover(function() {

  $(this).addClass('hover_edit_me');

  $(".hover_edit_me").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var big_parent = $(this);

    //edit text
    if (big_parent.attr("data-type") == 'text') {

      $("#sim-edit-text .text").val(big_parent.text());
      $("#sim-edit-text").fadeIn(500);
      $("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box").slideDown(500);

      $("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box-buttons-save").click(function() {
        big_parent.text($("#sim-edit-text .text").val());
      });
    }
  });


}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover_edit_me');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit_me" data-type="text">This is simple title</div>
<p class="edit_me" data-type="text">This is simple paragraph</p>

<hr/>

<!-- Edit Form -->
<div class="appName_edit" id="sim-edit-text">
  <div class="sim-edit-box">
    <div class="sim-edit-box-content">
      <small>Edit Text: </small>
      <div class="sim-edit-box-content-field">
        <textarea class="sim-edit-box-content-field-textarea text"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sim-edit-box-buttons">
      <div class="btn appName_btn_save sim-edit-box-buttons-save">Save</div>
      <div class="btn appName_btn_cancel sim-edit-box-buttons-cancel">Cancel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You *really* should not be binding click handler for every single mouseover event. That is just bad coding, because the event listeners quickly add up as the user hovers in and out. In general, binding event handlers within event handlers is not a good idea, and you should reconsider how you bind them.

Comment: @Terry how can you implement the same thing? any suggestions for clean code

Comment: The click event handlers can be defined outside the context of the hover event.

Comment: OK, I have move from hover to click event now, this works with @george solution. thats strange just defining the var outside fun makes it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `big_parent` out of all the function body and you're done.

```js
var big_parent
$(".edit_me").hover(function() {

  $(this).addClass('hover_edit_me');

  $(".hover_edit_me").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      big_parent = $(this);

    //edit text
    if (big_parent.attr("data-type") == 'text') {

      $("#sim-edit-text .text").val(big_parent.text());
      $("#sim-edit-text").fadeIn(500);
      $("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box").slideDown(500);

      $("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box-buttons-save").click(function() {
        big_parent.text($("#sim-edit-text .text").val());
      });
    }
  });


}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover_edit_me');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit_me" data-type="text">This is simple title</div>
<p class="edit_me" data-type="text">This is simple paragraph</p>

<hr/>

<!-- Edit Form -->
<div class="appName_edit" id="sim-edit-text">
  <div class="sim-edit-box">
    <div class="sim-edit-box-content">
      <small>Edit Text: </small>
      <div class="sim-edit-box-content-field">
        <textarea class="sim-edit-box-content-field-textarea text"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sim-edit-box-buttons">
      <div class="btn appName_btn_save sim-edit-box-buttons-save">Save</div>
      <div class="btn appName_btn_cancel sim-edit-box-buttons-cancel">Cancel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/63ujzwwn/3/)

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes it/what the problem was?

Comment: This is not really the right solution to the problem. The problem is every time you click on a .edit it adds another event handler to the save element

Comment: @George can you explain just by defining the var outside the function how it sloves?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is being caused by the fact that inside `$(".hover_edit_me").on('click', function(e) {` you are defining another click handler for `$("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box-buttons-save")`. - every time you click on a element to edit, you are making it so that hitting save updates that element, but it's still going to update other elements you've clicked on too.

There are a couple ways of solving this. One is to move the declaration of `big_parent` and to move the click event for `...-save` to outside the `.hover_edit_me` click event.

The other is to remove the events on the save element before applying the new one by adding `.off()`, like so:

`$("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box-buttons-save").off().click(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

Check below snippet

You can also solve by below way.
Instead of declaring a variable every time use variable directly
 $big_parent = $(this);

```js
$(".edit_me").hover(function() {

  $(this).addClass('hover_edit_me');

  $(".hover_edit_me").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $big_parent = $(this);

    //edit text
    if ($big_parent.attr("data-type") == 'text') {

      $("#sim-edit-text .text").val($big_parent.text());
      $("#sim-edit-text").fadeIn(500);
      $("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box").slideDown(500);

      $("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box-buttons-save").click(function() {
        $big_parent.text($("#sim-edit-text .text").val());
      });
    }
  });


}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover_edit_me');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit_me" data-type="text">This is simple title</div>
<p class="edit_me" data-type="text">This is simple paragraph</p>

<hr/>

<!-- Edit Form -->
<div class="appName_edit" id="sim-edit-text">
  <div class="sim-edit-box">
    <div class="sim-edit-box-content">
      <small>Edit Text: </small>
      <div class="sim-edit-box-content-field">
        <textarea class="sim-edit-box-content-field-textarea text"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sim-edit-box-buttons">
      <div class="btn appName_btn_save sim-edit-box-buttons-save">Save</div>
      <div class="btn appName_btn_cancel sim-edit-box-buttons-cancel">Cancel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.